# Convert String to ByteArray in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, byte, ascii

I want to convert a String to ByteArray in C# for Decrypt some data.

When I get de String from the ByteArray created, it shows question marks (?).

Example code:

```
        byte[] strTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData);

        MessageBox.Show(strData);
        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(strTemp));
```

> The string is "Ê<,,l"x¡" (With the double quotation mark) and the result to convert again to string is: ???l?x?

Comment: You need to use the right Encoding, may be source string wasn't in ASCII, try Unicode instead.

Comment: If you're trying to store arbitrary binary data in a string, you should be using base64 or hex to start with. We have no idea where your data is coming from, but it seems unlikely that it's following that rule...

Comment: Simply put: To decrypt, you need to reverse the encrypt steps. Please show them.

Answer (score 0):

I hope **this** helps you:

To Get *byte array* from a string

```
private byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
     System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
     return enc.GetBytes(str);
}
```

To get a *string* back from *byte array*:

```
private string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arr)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return enc.GetString(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For specific of that input, this BigEndianUnicode encoding seems works fine

```
byte[] strTemp = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strData);

MessageBox.Show(strData);
MessageBox.Show(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(strTemp));
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a byte array for the **ASCII** representation of your string, but your string is **Unicode**.

C# uses Unicode to encode strings, Unicode being able to represent far more symbols as ASCII.

In your example, every symbol which has no ASCII representation is replaced by '?', this is why only 'l' and 'x' appear in the output.

The proper way to do it is to use a Unicode encoding instead:

```
byte[] strTemp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);

MessageBox.Show(strData);
MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strTemp));
```

Basically, any Unicode encoding can be used: UTF8, UTF32, Unicode, BigEndianUnicode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings).