# How to fast convert a string array to a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, type-conversion, byte

I need to convert a string array to a byte array. I know this question has been posted and answered many times, but for some reason, none of the solutions work for me.

Here is the most common solution:

```
public static byte[] StringArrayToByteArray(string[] someStringArray)
{
    return someStringArray.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following errors: `FormatException: Could not find any parsable digits.` or `FormatException: Additional unparsable characters are at the end of the string.`

I need to save letters, along with a separator (/), for my data. Here is my code:

```
        string[] stringArray = new string[map.Size.x * map.Size.y];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int y = (int) map.Rect.y; y < map.Rect.yMax; y++)
        {
            for (int x = (int) map.Rect.x; x < map.Rect.xMax; x++)
            {
                stringArray[counter] = map[x,y].Name;
                stringArray[counter] += "/";
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

Then I need to convert this string[] to a byte array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert String to Byte Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545162/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-array) and [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp) and [Convert String to ByteArray in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968961/convert-string-to-bytearray-in-c-sharp) and [Convert String\[\] to byte\[\] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531148/convert-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: No. Appending data to an existing string is extremely slow in my case. I need to be able to convert a string array to a byte array, fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine those strings to a single string and return its byte[]. ie:

```
public static byte[] StringArrayToByteArray(string[] someStringArray)
{
    return string.Join("",someStringArray).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Simple, and works surprisingly fast. Thank you!

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you for the suggestions. I didn't think to join the entire array first and then perform the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way (performance-wise) to do this is to use one of the overloads of `Encoding.GetBytes` which allows for a supplied `byte[]` buffer.

This is only going to work with an encoding which is fixed width, either `Unicode` or `ASCII`. It's not clear which encoding you want. The reason you got that error is because of characters that won't fit in a `byte`, so I've gone with `Unicode`.

```cs
public static byte[] StringArrayToByteArray(string[] someStringArray)
{
    var buffer = new byte[someStringArray.Sum(s => s.Length) * 2];   // remove * 2 for ASCII
    var position = 0;
    foreach (var s in someStringArray)
        position += Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s, o, s.Length, buffer, position);

    return buffer;
}
```

You can also use the new `Span<byte>` overload in newer versions of .NET